# Calucating the total number of cells in a row that are less than 16 hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, vba

I need the total number of cells in sheet-1 Column B that are less than 16 hours where Sheet-1 Column A is not equal to 5 in sheet 1 E4 cell.

For Ex please see the image attached.

[Please click on this link to find the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gJa2.jpg)

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

- column A of sheet1 are date/times, and not text, and
- you are attempting to find how many date/times are more than 16 hours old

then you simply want to place the following formula in sheet2!F7:

```
=COUNTIF(sheet1!A:A,"<"&NOW()-0.75)
```

(16 hours is 0.75 of a day.)

---

If the data in column A is text, then it gets slightly harder as you have to ensure that Excel does not treat the `NOW()-0.75` as a date/time.  You can trick it by adding an extraneous character to the end of the formatted date/time so that it no longer appears to be valid, e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(sheet1!A:A,"<"&TEXT(NOW()-0.75,"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")&"#")
```

worked for me.  (The extra `"#"` at the end forced it to no longer be a valid date/time string.)

Comment: Hi YowE3K Thanks for the Answer I will try it in the morning...  Can you please check if you can help in the below requirement wanted to create automatic dropdown list in cell D2 with the old of C2 (date field)

For ex: Initially C2=2017/03/20 D2 should have dropdown with no values. If I change C2=2017/03/27 D2 drop down list should get a value as 2017/03/20. Again If I change C2=2017/04/10 D2 drop down list should get values as 2017/03/20 & 2017/03/27.

Comment: @HarishReddy That sounds completely unrelated to this question, so I suggest you raise a new question to obtain the answer.  (And I'm probably not the best person to answer any question regarding dropdown lists.)

Comment: Hi YowE3K there are few changes in my requirement can you please check and help me with that.

Comment: @HarishReddy Just change it to a `COUNTIFS` and use both criteria.  My guess is that will be `=COUNTIFS(sheet1!B:B,"<"&NOW()-0.75,sheet1!A:A,"<>"&sheet1!E4)` but this is fairly elementary - you should really do your own testing for this sort of thing.